# why can not update data?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an update function, data can not be changed :

```
function editAnggota($data,$id){

        $i=0;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if(!is_int($value)){
                $arrayValue[$i] = $key. " = '".$value."'";
            }else{
            $arrayValue[$i] = $key. " = ".$value;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $nilai = implode(', ', $arrayValue);


    $s = "UPDATE `anggota` SET $nilai 
            WHERE id = '$id'";

    $sql = $this->db->prepare($s) or die(' error : '.$this->db->error);

    $sql->execute();
    if(!$sql){
        die('Koneksi error : '.$this->db->error);
    }
    if($sql){
        header("location: ?op=anggota");
    }else{
        echo "gagal";
    }
}
```

when my initiation :

$db = new Database();

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $jk = $_POST['jk'];
    $tempat = $_POST['tempat'];
    $tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
    $formattgl = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('$tanggal'));
    $pekerjaan = $_POST['pekerjaan'];
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $fotonama = str_replace(' ', '-', $id.'.jpg');
    $filefoto = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], '../asset/img/anggota/'.$fotonama);

    $data = array(
        'id'=>$id,
        'nama'=>$nama,
        'jk'=>$jk,
        'tempat'=>$tempat,
        'tanggal'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime('tanggal')),
        'pekerjaan'=>$pekerjaan,
        'alamat'=>$alamat,
        'foto'=>$fotonama
        );

    $db->editAnggota($data,$_GET['id']);

    }
```

why can not update the data?
and fixed data
it looks like I've done right, with the right query anyway, why did they fail?

Comment: echo `$s` and check your query!!

Comment: are you getting an error? also you use prepare but then you still insert the variable directly into the query, this way you're query is still vulnerable to sql injection!

Answer (score 0):

Although what you are doing is possibly correct, I think this is probably not what you want:

```
$db->editAnggota($data,$_GET['id']);
```

Do you perhaps need this?

```
$db->editAnggota($data,$_POST['id']);
```

Apart from that you should use placeholders for your variable values as now you have an sql injection problem. You could even be causing the problems with the query yourself if one of the values contains a quote `'`.

You could do something like:

```
$arrayValue = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $arrayValue[] =  "$key = :$key";
    $values[":" . $key] = $value;
}
$nilai = implode(', ', $arrayValue);

$s = "UPDATE `anggota` SET $nilai 
        WHERE id = :idd";

$values[':idd'] = $data['id'];

$sql = $this->db->prepare($s) or die(' error : '.$this->db->error);

$sql->execute($values);
```

Comment: error appears: 1054-Unknown column '3rrdsafd' in 'where clause'.
why?